# Use PHP to display a CSV-based Graph

Tags: php, parsing, csv

Sorry, I'm a n00b to web languages. I'm trying to upload a CSV file, parse the second and seventh columns, and output it to the Google Graphs API. This is my first ever time trying to do anything with PHP, so, a example would be nice for me to analyze, but, I can try to figure out everything with documentation as well.

Thank you so much for help in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how you can upload a file with PHP: http://de3.php.net/move_uploaded_file
Parsing a CSV file is easy:

```
$csv = file('path/to/file.csv');
foreach ($csv as &$current) {
  $current = explode(';', $current);
}
```

If you then loop through `$csv` you have the second and seventh column in `$csv[$iterator][1]` and `$csv[$iterator][6]`.

I haven't used Googles Graph API, so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not married to google graphs, try [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).  I've used it on several occasions and really like it.  They have some tutorials and good sample code to look at, too.

Check the other response for parsing a CSV file; it's spot on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a component designed to easily implement the graph by uploading the CSV file: [Graph from CSV file](http://www.claromentis.com/wiki/help%3asmart_objects%3acsv_graph?do=show)